# silence next AxiosError popup for non-2XX status codes

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios

I have a pretty standard API endpoint that returns status codes depending on the result of the request.

For example, a failed login attempt will return a `statusCode` of `401 (Unauthorized)`.

I'm handling these errors by using a `switch` statement on the status:

```
const uri = `${process.env.API_ENDPOINT}/user/auth/login`;
const request = await axios.post(uri, { email, password });

switch(request.status){
    case 401:
        // Display an error to the user
        break;
    case 200:
        // Redirect the user
        break;
    // Etc...
}
```

But, since I'm not wrapping the request in a `try/catch`, I get this constant *annoying* popup from **Next** whenever I'm testing failures:

> AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401

I don't need this. A simple `console.error` is fine. *How do I silence this popup?*